# How to emit many colors at once?

Tags: texturing, materials, lighting, emission

Is it possible to have "multi-color" emission?

For instance if I was modeling an iPhone, I would want the phone's screen to emit light - but not just one color. I'd want the light emitted to exactly match the colors of the screen that's emitting:

[image: iPhone]

Unfortunately I can't seem to find any possible way to accomplish this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you talking about emitting multiple colors  with one material?

Comment: Yes, if possible. If there is another way to do this, I'm open to suggestions as well. Basically, I want an image (the iPhone's screen in my screenshot) to emit light corresponding to the actual colors used in the screenshot itself. This would look way more realistic than a single emission color.

Comment: Hey :). You could simply run an image texture through the emission node...

Comment: well, I think there is a way to achieve what you are trying to accomplish with mapping nodes among other things, but with something as complex as an i-phone, that would be a nightmare. what I would recommend doing, is making multiple materials, each with different emission settings, and then select the parts of the mesh you want to be effected by the desired lighting, and then assign the appropriate material.  (I hope all that made sense)

Comment: @Jachym Michal - that would be great, thank you! Is there any way you could post a screenshot of the required node setup? I am not very good with nodes and more complex material setups.

Comment: If using Eevee, you also have to activate screen space reflections.

Comment: @lemon - Thanks! I'll keep that in my notes. I typically only use Cycles though.

Comment: ok, so the nodes are simply image texture/emission/material output as @JachymMichal said.

Comment: Got it, I'll give it a go. Thanks much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to illustrate my comment :-).
Simply run an image texture through the *Emission node*.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to be of help, good luck with your project :).